# How to focus a error after disable button 1st click using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have written code in asp.net for disable button after 1st click. Code is below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CssClass="btn btnBlue btnStep" Text="Submit" 
                OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ServiceFee" OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'In progress...';__doPostBack('btnNext','')" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

It is working fine no problem but now I need to add little extra functionality i.e. I need to focus on error. When user clicks on submit button without entering card details or personal details it will show error at empty text box and suddenly page will reload, because **i have written dopostback in javascript.** So how to focus on error and  after postback need to show error?

Comment: Made an ajax call and check if it is success or not, if failure you can show your validation message or failure reason on the page without reloading it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `btnNext` event you can have something like

```
// Supose txtCardDetails is the TextBox with the card details
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCardDetails.Text))
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "document.getElementById('" + txtCardDetails.ClientID + "').focus();");
    return; // Maybe you want to do something before leave the event method
}
```

this will send a script to focus the field, ***BUT***, I recommend to do the validation in the client side (JS) and in the Server side (C#), so, validating this in the client side should be like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" ... 
            OnClientClick="return SubmitIfValid(this);" ...  />


function SubmitIfValid(el) {
   if(document.getElementById('<%= txtCardDetails.ClientID %>').value === ''){
      alert('invalid card details');
      document.getElementById('<%= txtCardDetails.ClientID %>').focus();
      return false;
   }

   // more validations

   // if all is OK then...
   el.disabled = true; 
   el.value = 'In progress...';
   __doPostBack('btnNext','')
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation controls like `validationSummary`. Managing errors like those by yourself can be very difficult.